# Import arrays using python

Tags: python, pycharm

I have (excel files with measurements taken from grayscale images(stacks).

How can i import these arrays in the python code?

i need to create a database? I am using Pycharm. Also should i import the file names of my images or just the measurements from them? And the last question is : Can i load a stack in Pycharm? Because i have 3 stacks of images(3 datasets).

```
 from random import randint
    import cv2
    import nump as np
    from sklearn import svm
    from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, accuracy_score
    from imblearn.metrics import geometric_mean_score
    from math import sqrt

    offset = 20
    samples_number = 200

    def learn(eye_type):
        prefix = "h" if eye_type == "healthy" else "dr"
        # the picture on which the classifier will be training
          training_image = cv2.imread(eye_type + "Drusen RPE_/0002" + prefix + ".tif")
        # slice 700x700, on this section the classifier teaches
          training_image = training_image[700:1400,700:1400,:]

        training_expert_mask = cv2.imread(eye_type + "_manualsegm/01_" + prefix + ".tif")
        training_expert_mask = training_expert_mask[700:1400,700:1400,:]

        train_x = np.zeros((samples_number, (2*offset)**2))
        train_y = np.zeros((samples_number))

        # preparation of the training set
        # drawing a point on our slice and surrounding it with the given offset
        for i in range(0,samples_number):
            x = randint(0+offset, training_image.shape[0]-offset)
            y = randint(0+offset, training_image.shape[1]-offset)
            crop_img = training_image[x-offset:x+offset, y-offset:y+offset]
            flattened = crop_img[:,:,1].flatten()
            train_x[i,:] = flattened
            train_y[i] = training_expert_mask[x,y,1]/255

        clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                            hidden_layer_sizes=(offset, 2), random_state=1)

        # train_x to matrix [content of sample] x [number of samples]
        # train_y to a vector containing an inf or a pixel in the expert's image mask is a background or a vessel
        clf.fit(train_x, train_y)
        return clf

    def predict(clf, img_num, eye_type):
        prefix = "h" if eye_type == "healthy" else "dr"
        # prediction throughout the image
        img_to_be_processed = cv2.imread(eye_type + "/" + img_num + "_" + prefix + ".jpg")
        expert_result = cv2.imread(eye_type + "_manualsegm/" + img_num + "_" + prefix + ".tif")

        predict_x = np.zeros(((img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-2*offset), (2*offset)**2))

        res = np.zeros(((img_to_be_processed.shape[0]-2*offset) * (img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-2*offset)))
        for i in range(offset, img_to_be_processed.shape[0]-offset):
            a = 0
            for j in range(offset, img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-offset):
                predict_crop_img = img_to_be_processed[i-offset:i+offset, j-offset:j+offset]
                predict_x[a,:] = predict_crop_img[:,:,1].flatten()
                a=a+1
            res[(i-offset) * (img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-2*offset) : (i-offset) * (img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-2*offset)+a] = clf.predict(predict_x)

        learned_result = res.reshape((img_to_be_processed.shape[0]-2*offset, img_to_be_processed.shape[1]-2*offset))
        learned_result = learned_result*255
        expert_result = expert_result[:,:,1] # I choose only 1 channel (always in the black and white picture all 3 are the same)

        # preparation of input data to the report with correspondence
        # test mask
        fovmask = cv2.imread(eye_type + "_fovmask/" + img_num + "_" + prefix + "_mask.tif")
        fovmask = fovmask[:,:,1] # I choose only 1 channell (always in the black and white picture all 3 are the same)

        # drawing pictures
        # cv2.imshow("cropped", learned_result)
        # cv2.imshow("cropped2", expert_result)
        # cv2.imshow("fovmask", fovmask)
        learned_result_with_offset = np.zeros(fovmask.shape); # at the beginning, I fill the matrix with the size of the mask with zeros
        learned_result_with_offset[offset: -offset,offset: -offset] = learned_result # I will supplement our result with missing offsets

        # picture with a mask put on
        learned_result_with_mask = learned_result_with_offset[fovmask==255]
        expert_result_with_mask = expert_result[fovmask==255]

        #flattening the results in order to prepare for the input counting the relevancy
        learned_result_with_mask = learned_result_with_mask.flatten()
        expert_result_with_mask = expert_result_with_mask.flatten()

        recalled_vessel_score = recall_score(expert_result_with_mask, learned_result_with_mask, average='macro')
        recalled_background_score = recall_score(255 - expert_result_with_mask, 255 - learned_result_with_mask, average='macro')
        accured_score = accuracy_score(expert_result_with_mask, learned_result_with_mask)
        geometric_avg_score = geometric_mean_score(expert_result_with_mask, learned_result_with_mask)

        print (img_num + " recalled_score", recalled_vessel_score)
        print (img_num + " accured_score", accured_score)
        print (img_num + " recalled_background_score", recalled_background_score)
        print (img_num + " geometric_avg_score", geometric_avg_score)

        return recalled_vessel_score, accured_score, recalled_background_score, geometric_avg_score

        # cv2.waitKey(0) to wait for any key after displaying photos

    print ("start learning")
    clf = learn("healthy") # healthy, diabetic_retinopathy- chore

    recalled_vessel_scores = 0
    accured_scores = 0
    recalled_background_scores = 0
    geometric_avg_scores = 0

    file_nums_arr = ["02"]

    print ("start anticipation for healthy")
    # for healthy
    for file_num in file_nums_arr:
        recalled_vessel_score, accured_score, recalled_background_score, geometric_avg_score = predict(clf, file_num, "healthy")
        recalled_vessel_scores += recalled_vessel_score
        accured_scores += accured_score
        recalled_background_scores += recalled_background_score
        geometric_avg_scores += geometric_avg_score

    print ("================= FINAL RESULTS FOR THE HEALTH=================")
    print ("average vascular accuracy: ", recalled_vessel_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average goodness: ", accured_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average accuracy background: ", recalled_background_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average geometric mean: ", geometric_avg_scores / len(file_nums_arr))

    recalled_vessel_scores = 0
    accured_scores = 0
    recalled_background_scores = 0
    geometric_avg_scores = 0

    print ("start anticipating for the patient")
    # for the patient
    for file_num in file_nums_arr:
        recalled_vessel_score, accured_score, recalled_background_score, geometric_avg_score = predict(clf, file_num, "diabetic_retinopathy")
        recalled_vessel_scores += recalled_vessel_score
        accured_scores += accured_score
        recalled_background_scores += recalled_background_score
        geometric_avg_scores += geometric_avg_score

    print ("================= FINAL RESULTS FOR THE SICK =================")
    print ("average aptitude of the vessel: ", recalled_vessel_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average general aptitude: ", accured_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average accuracy background: ", recalled_background_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
    print ("average geometric mean: ", geometric_avg_scores / len(file_nums_arr))
```

Comment: pycharm is an IDE for python. Python is the lenguaje to do it.

Comment: Please try to reformulate your question to make it easier for contributors to find an answer. The title refers to 'arrays', presumably tables of data coming from an Excel file, but the code snippet that you have doesn't seem to attempt to load any file at all. When you say 'import', do you mean 'read and convert to Python objects (e.g., lists or `numpy` arrays or similar dataframe objects)? If you need simply to read excel files from Python, there are several options, e.g. the `xlrd`, or `python-excel` libraries or exporting the data as CSV and reading it with the `csv` module.